# d3 line chart not getting terminated

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I am using d3.js along with dc.js and Crossfilter. As seen on the below image, the chart should end on 12/31/2016 as there is no data after that but keeps on going. Probably stuck at the last value. This is only happening in line chart. When I use a bar chart it does not happen.

Is this a known bug? Not sure what else I can do? I copied the configuration exactly from the dc.js example page (composite chart) and applied my dataset.

[image]

Comment: This is a little tricky without some code, can you share some relevant bits, or post [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My dimensions were based on dates and some records had a typo in them. Instead of 2013, it had 2103 which caused the problem.